# Разница между функцией и методом в ООП С++

Tags: c++, классы, struct

В литературе сказано, что между struct и class есть общие то, что оба они могут местить в себе элементы-данные и элементы-функции. НО так же сказано, что отличаются они тем, что class в себе может содержать ЕЩЕ И функции-методы с элементами-данными. Выходит функции и метод не одно и тоже?

Comment: Разница между `class` и `struct` чисто косметическая: они отличаются только спецификаторами доступа и наследования по умолчанию (у `class` — `private`, у `struct` — `public`). В остальном они совершенно идентичны и [даже взаимозаменяемы](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b32def14ddd13008) (если не учитывать то, что у ключевого слова `class` есть второе значение: оно используется также для объявления параметров-типов шаблонов).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Либо вы что-то не поняли, либо в упоминаемой "литературе" написана какая-то белиберда.

При объявлении классов не существует никакой функциональной разницы между `class` и `struct`. Все различия сводятся лишь к правам доступа по умолчанию.

Жестких определений для терминов *функция* и *метод*, которые бы позволили отделить эти понятия, не существует. Обычно *методом* называют функцию-член класса. Иногда подразумевают, что *метод* - это именно *нестатическая* функция-член класса.

Формально *функция* - понятие более общее, покрывающее как самостоятельные функции, так и функции-члены классов. То есть *метод* - это всегда *функция*, в то время как *функция* - это не обязательно *метод*.